# Scale in associative arrays

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to print an associative array with decimals but I don't know the way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

quantity="quantity.csv"
line=20
declare -A addQuantity
declade -A average
declare -A numberOfQuantity
for i in `seq 2 $line`
do
name=`cat $quantity | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f4`
quantity=`cat $quantity | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f5`
addQuantity[$name]=$((addQuantity[$name]+quantity))
numberOfQuantity[$name]=$((numberOfQuantity[$name]+1))
done

for i in `seq 2 $line`
do
name=`cat $quantity | sort -n -k2 -t"," | head -n$i | tail -n1 | cut -d ',' -f4`
average[$name]=$((addQuantity[$name]/numberOfQuantity[$name]))
echo "$name - $quantity - ${addQuantity[$name] - $ {numberOfQuantity[$name]} - ${average[$name]}"
done
```

This works good but I want to print the average with decimals.
My file .csv is that:

```
[...],[...],[...],name,quantity

0,0,0,name1,4

0,0,0,name1, 7

0,0,0,name2,10

0,0,0,name3,4

0,0,0,name3,6
```

Comment: Bash is not supporting floating point to my knowledge. In the bash world, you would have to use some external software, like bc to have the average with decimal.

Comment: You can use ksh or zsh instead. They support floating point if you do e.g. `echo $((1.0 * 3/4))` (just 3/4 by itself would be integer division)

Comment: Or, at least is ksh, set your variable as floating with typeset -Fn {variable name} (n optional, being the number of decimal digit to be output)